# Java-Stream - Split, group and map the data from a String using a single Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a string as below:

```
String data = "010$$fengtai,010$$chaoyang,010$$haidain,027$$wuchang,027$$hongshan,027$$caidan,021$$changnin,021$$xuhui,020$$tianhe";
```

And I want to convert it into a map of type `Map<String,List<String>>` (like shown below) by performing the following steps:

- first split the string by `,` and then split by `$$`;
- the substring before `$$` would serve as a Key while grouping the data, and the substring after `$$` needs to placed inside into a list, which would be a Value of the Map.

*Example of the resulting Map:*

```
{ 
  027=[wuchang, hongshan, caidan],
  020=[tianhe],
  010=[fengtai, chaoyang, haidain],
  021=[changnin, xuhui]
}
```

I've used a traditional way of achieving this:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> parseParametersByIterate(String sensors) {
    List<String[]> dataList = Arrays.stream(sensors.split(","))
        .map(s -> s.split("\\$\\$"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String[] d : dataList) {
        List<String> list = resultMap.get(d[0]);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(d[1]);
            resultMap.put(d[0], list);
        } else {
            list.add(d[1]);
        }
    }
    return resultMap;
}
```

But it seems more complicated and verbose. Thus, I want to implement this logic **one-liner** (i.e. a single stream statement).

What I have tried so far is below

```
Map<String, List<String>> result =  Arrays.stream(data.split(","))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\$\\$")[0]));
```

But the output doesn't match the one I want to have. How can I generate a Map structured as described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to map the values of the mapping. You can do that by specifying a second argument to `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("\\$\\$")[0],
    Collectors.mapping(s -> s.split("\\$\\$")[1],
        Collectors.toList()
))
```

Instead of then splitting twice, you can split first and group afterwards:

```
Arrays.stream(data.split(","))
    .map(s -> s.split("\\$\\$"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],
        Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1],Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Which now outputs:

```
{027=[wuchang, hongshan, caidan], 020=[tianhe], 021=[changnin, xuhui], 010=[fengtai, chaoyang, haidain]}
```

Comment: Yeah,I do not want to split twice,thanks for your answer,will accpet it after 15 minutes

Comment: You can improve the performance even more by using `.map(s -> s.split("\\$\\$", 2))` as this will tell the `split` operation that it doesn’t have to search for another `$$` after it found one.

Comment: By the way, `split(",")` and `split("\\$\\$")` can be combined in a single step without producing intermediate arrays - [*see*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74692573/17949945).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the required information from the string **without** allocating intermediate arrays and by iterating over the string **only once** and also employing the regex engine **only once** instead of doing multiple `String.split()` calls and splitting first by coma `,` then by `$$`. We can get all the needed data in one go.

Since you're already using regular expressions (*because interpreting* `"\\s\\s"` *requires utilizing the regex engine*), it would be wise to leverage them to the full power.

## [`Matcher.results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results())

We can define the following Pattern that captures the pieces of you're interested in:

```
public static final Pattern DATA = // use the proper name to describe a piece of information (like "027$$hongshan") that the pattern captures
    Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\$\\$(\\w+)");
```

Using this pattern, we can produce an instance of `Matcher` and apply Java 9 method `Matcher.result()`, which produces a stream of `MatchResult`s.

`MatchResult` is an object encapsulating information about the captured sequence of characters. We can access the groups using method `MatchResult.group()`.

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> parseParametersByIterate(String sensors) {
    
    return DATA.matcher(sensors).results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            matchResult -> matchResult.group(1),     // extracting "027" from "027$$hongshan"
            Collectors.mapping(
                matchResult -> matchResult.group(2), // extracting "hongshan" from "027$$hongshan"
                Collectors.toList())
        ));
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "010$$fengtai,010$$chaoyang,010$$haidain,027$$wuchang,027$$hongshan,027$$caidan,021$$changnin,021$$xuhui,020$$tianhe";
    
    parseParametersByIterate(data)
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
}
```

*Output:*

```
027 -> [wuchang, hongshan, caidan]
020 -> [tianhe]
021 -> [changnin, xuhui]
010 -> [fengtai, chaoyang, haidain]
```